# RabbitMQ: Is there a way to differ a message dispatch to a later time?

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

I am using RabbitMQ via ampq in nodejs and would like to set up a work queue to hold some data(messages) that would be needed to fire some operations at a later time.

I understand that RabbitMQ dispatches all available messages in a queue to available consumers but in my case, I want certain messages to come at their scheduled time.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is possible within the confines of RabbitMQ but you could use a node cron to schedule a listener on a specific queue at a specific time. For instance I have a scheduler that at midnight it starts listening to the queue and pulls all the messages from the day and then processes the messages completely and empties the queue before going silent and waiting for the next scheduled run.

Comment: Thanks Jeymz, I think I will just go for the regular cronjob.

Comment: you should checkout node-cron. It's super easy to implement and allows you to control the cron from the config.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron